# How to get Linux kernel vermagic from a source tree?

Tags: linux, kernel, source-code

It is used when installing to `/lib/modules`
It is printed after `make modules_install`

Part of it is returned by `scripts/setlocalversion`.

How to just get it without running `make modules_install`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cat include/generated/utsrelease.h
```